# MS Access, Conditional Sum based on Criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, conditional-statements

I created a query in MS Access to summarize adjustments by loan # if they are type AA or RA. I need help converting this to SQL which will work in access.

```
SELECT 
    RLI_ManualInterest.[Loan Account Number], 
    SUM(RLI_ManualInterest.[Loan Int Adjustment]) AS [SumOfLoan Int Adjustment],
    RLI_ManualInterest.[GLAcct Interest]
FROM 
    RLI_ManualInterest
WHERE
    (((RLI_ManualInterest.[Adjustment Type]) IN ("AA","RA")))
GROUP BY 
    RLI_ManualInterest.[Loan Account Number];
```

I need to create two fields, one will contain the sum of Int Adjustments if Adjustment type is AA or RA and will be called [Loan Int Reaccr Adj Mtd] and the other will contain the sum of Int adjustments if the adjustment type is FX, GL, or FF.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: msaccess has a feature that will convert your query to sql.  Check that.

Comment: Folks, this is SQL. Convert to what? Did you mean SQL Server? SQL is a programming language that even MS Access uses. Please tag and describe appropriately.

Comment: @Mike: Please don't add "[SOLVED]" to the title - by accepting an answer your question is marked as solved (the answer symbol has a different color in the question list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the below conditional sum expressions using `CASE WHEN` which most RDMS' use for logical inline expressions. One exception though is incidentally MS Access whose ACE/JET SQL dialect does not carry `CASE WHEN`. But using [pass-through queries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Process-SQL-on-a-database-server-by-using-a-pass-through-query-b775ac23-8a6b-49b2-82e2-6dac62532a42) you can still run other native SQL dialects in the MS Access GUI program to interact with backend databases (SQL Server, MySQL, Postgre, DB2, Oracle, etc). 
) via ODBC/OLEDB connections.

```
SELECT RLI_ManualInterest.[Loan Account Number],

       SUM(CASE WHEN RLI_ManualInterest.[Adjustment Type] IN ('AA', 'RA') 
                THEN RLI_ManualInterest.[Loan Int Adjustment]
                ELSE 0 
           END) AS [SumOfLoan Int Adjustment],

       SUM(CASE WHEN RLI_ManualInterest.[Adjustment Type] IN ('FX', 'GL', 'FF') 
                THEN RLI_ManualInterest.[Loan Int Adjustment]
                ELSE 0 
           END) AS [SumOfLoan Int Reaccr Adj Mtd]

FROM RLI_ManualInterest
GROUP BY RLI_ManualInterest.[Loan Account Number];
```

Alternatively, the equivalent to above in MS Access is using the logical [IIF()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) function (which is [available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) starting in SQL Server 2012). Of these two, no other popular RDMS uses `IIF()`:

```
SELECT RLI_ManualInterest.[Loan Account Number],

       SUM(IIF(RLI_ManualInterest.[Adjustment Type] IN ('AA', 'RA'), 
               RLI_ManualInterest.[Loan Int Adjustment],
               0)) AS [SumOfLoan Int Adjustment],

       SUM(IIF(RLI_ManualInterest.[Adjustment Type] IN ('FX', 'GL', 'FF'),
               RLI_ManualInterest.[Loan Int Adjustment],
               0)) AS [SumOfLoan Int Reaccr Adj Mtd]

FROM RLI_ManualInterest
GROUP BY RLI_ManualInterest.[Loan Account Number];
```

Comment: Wow that's perfect! Thank you!